# Distributed CRON in Kubernetes

Tags: java, spring, cron, jvm, kubernetes

distributed CRON in Kubernetes is still a work in progress (https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/2156).

What do you use for CRON jobs in Kubernetes today?

Do you recommend any solution that works well with Spring/JVM-based services? Spring/JVM startup time is quite high and if CRON scheduler started a new JVM for each job, startup time might be much higher than time of actual work - is there any solution that could run the job in existing JVM?

Thank you,
Jakub

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think [Mesos Chronos](https://github.com/mesos/chronos) is still ideal solution.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a small [Go app](https://github.com/IanLewis/homepage/blob/master/deploy/gocron/main.go) that functions like cron but writes log info to stdout (no email!) and can be built into a static binary for easy containerization.

I built kubectl from source as a static binary and included it in the image (it may be a static binary in the most recent releases). Kubectl will automatically look for the service account token/certs in /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ so you should be good to go unless you're not using the default service account.

I then set up a [crontab](https://github.com/IanLewis/homepage/blob/master/deploy/gocron/crontab-prod) to run kubectl to create a [job](https://github.com/IanLewis/homepage/blob/master/deploy/backup/backup.yaml) at the period that I wanted. The crontab and yaml files for the jobs can be mounted as a secret. You can either use [conf2kube](https://github.com/kelseyhightower/conf2kube) or some other way of generating the secrets. I wrote a simple [python script](https://github.com/IanLewis/homepage/blob/master/deploy/gocron/create_secrets.pyhttps://github.com/IanLewis/homepage/blob/master/deploy/gocron/create_secrets.py).

It's totally a workaround until there is proper support but I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using cron jobs in kubernetes with java, each job launches a new JVM, so no. No reuse here.
To reuse you must jave something like a webapp always running and schedule jobs to run inside this already running app.